# IJCADのGetPointでラバーバンドができない

Tags: ijcad

AcadからIJCADへのコンバートをしています。下記コードのGetEntityでクリック点座標を
取得し、それをGetPointへ渡していますがラバーバンドをしてもらえません。何か別の方法があるのでしょうか？

```vb
Dim ptPick As Object = Nothing    'ptPickはﾋﾟｯｸ位置

ptPick = Nothing
On Error Resume Next 'GetEntityでErrの場合ｽﾙｰさせる
'------------------<管または桝を選択>
DOC.Utility.GetEntity(Myobj, ptPick, vbCrLf & txt)
'------------------
If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo UU 'Pickはずれの場合
x1 = ptPick(0)
y1 = ptPick(1)
ChkPrint("ｸﾘｯｸ点=(" & Format(x1, "0.00") & "," & _
             Format(y1, "0.00") & ") ｸﾘｯｸしたものは" & _
             Myobj.objectName & " Lay=" & Myobj.Layer)

'------------------<表示位置始点ｸﾘｯｸ> IJCADではﾗﾊﾞｰﾊﾞﾝﾄﾞできない
ptPick = DOC.Utility.GetPoint(ptPick, _
         "描き出し位置をクリックして下さい:")
'------------------
If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo UU
x2 = ptPick(0)
y2 = ptPick(1)
```

ソースコードを以下に書換えて実行して見ました

```
    Dim ptPick(0 To 2) As Double
    On Error Resume Next 'GetEntityでErrの場合ｽﾙｰさせる
    '------------------<管または桝を選択>
    DOC.Utility.GetEntity(Myobj, ptPick, vbCrLf & txt)
    '------------------
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo UU 'Pickはずれの場合
    x1 = ptPick(0)
    y1 = ptPick(1)

    Dim ptPick2(0 To 2) As Double
    On Error Resume Next
    '------------------<表示位置始点ｸﾘｯｸ> IJCADではﾗﾊﾞｰﾊﾞﾝﾄﾞできない
    ptPick2 = DOC.Utility.GetPoint(ptPick, vbCrLf & _
              "描き出し位置をクリックして下さい:")
    '------------------
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo UU
    x2 = ptPick2(0)
    y2 = ptPick2(1)
```

これでもラバーバンドが出ません？（座標は正常に得られています）

これから以下をやってみます
（１）参考のコードをそのままコピーして実行してみる
（２）何か環境の問題かもしれないのでIJCADの設定を調べてみる

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ptPick As Object = Nothing    'ptPickはﾋﾟｯｸ位置
```

を

```
Dim ptPick As Variant  'ptPickはﾋﾟｯｸ位置
```

に変更してみてください。

追記①
VB.NET2008であれば、

```
Dim ptPick(0 To 2) As Double
```

に変更してみてください。

追記②
エンティティの選択、座標の入力、エンティティの移動を行うサンプルコードを作成して、IJCAD上で実行してみたところ問題なくラバーバンドが表示されていました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

サンプルコードは以下の通りです。

```
Dim app As GcadApplication = New GcadApplication
app.Visible = True
If app.Documents.Count = 0 Then
    app.Quit()
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim doc As GcadDocument = app.ActiveDocument

Dim center(0 To 2) As Double
center(0) = 50
center(1) = 50
center(2) = 0
doc.ModelSpace.AddCircle(center, 50.0)

Dim obj As GcadEntity = Nothing
Dim pickPt1(0 To 2) As Double
doc.Utility.GetEntity(obj, pickPt1, vbCrLf + "Select entity")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo EndLabel

Dim pickPt2(0 To 2) As Double
pickPt2 = doc.Utility.GetPoint(pickPt1, vbCrLf + "Input point")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo EndLabel

obj.Move(pickPt1, pickPt2)

EndLabel:
app.Quit()
```

Comment: 投稿者です。VB.Net2008を使っています。型 Variant は指定できないので Dim ptPick as VariantType にすると x1=ptPick(0) がエラーになるので、Dim ptPick(2) as VariantTypeにして実行しました。すると GetEntityで「型'Double()'から型'VariantType()'への変換は無効です」のエラーになります。VariantTypeではなくDoubleにすると実行できますがラバーバンドはしてくれません。IJCADの開発者ヘルプにも例題がないので困っています。

Comment: Dim ptPick(0 to 2) as Double にしてみました。実行は出来てクリック位置は取得できますが、ラバーバンドが出てきません（As Object時と同じ現象でした）。

Comment: サンプルコードで実行するとラバーバンドできました。当方のコードもapp,doc,obj等を定義し直して実行してみます

Comment: 型宣言で Public ACAD As Object, Public DOC As Object を Public ACAD As GcadApplication = New GcadApplication, Public DOC As GcadDocument = ACAD.ActiveDocument に変更し、関数内では Dim Myobj As Object = New Object を Dim Myobj As GcadEntity = Nothng に変更して実行すると正常にラバーバンドできました。

Comment: 【追記】今までは参照COMを使わずに作成していましたが型宣言をする為に GcadDynblocklib.dll と GcadVbaLib.dll をCOMに追加して上記のようにソースを変更しました。（今までは先にAcadを立ち上げてから本ソフトを実行していました。従ってAcadEntityなどの宣言はできずObjectで代用していました）